# Streaming with gunicorn

Tags: python, timeout, flask, streaming, gunicorn

I'm trying to stream data from a flask/gunicorn server:

```
while (True):
    result = json.dumps(tweetQueue.get())
    yield result
```

However, 30 seconds into the stream, gunicorn times out my connection and stops the stream. How can I make the timeout such that publishing new data to the stream from the server will restart the timeout so the stream will not be terminated?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this `gunicorn` parameter is relevant? http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/develop/configure.html#timeout

Comment: Yes, I considered that - it seemed really inelegant to just set a large timeout value, and I couldn't see a way to turn off the timeout entirely. 
Besides, ideally I would still have a useful timeout in case the connection really is lost, but the timeout would be reset when new data is published.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am answering my own question after doing some more research.

```
gunicorn server:app -k gevent
```

This uses asynchronous workers, which have the benefit of using `Connection: keep-alive` when serving requests. This allows the request to be served indefinitely.

Comment: This answer sounds good, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I am using Python 2.7 and gunicorn 0.14.5 and gevent 0.13.6. Which versions are you using?

Comment: Unlike the comment above suggests this method still works. But remember to install `gevent` before trying this. For reference, first install greenlet using `pip install greenlet` and then GEvent using `pip install gevent`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the built-in `BaseHTTPServer` instead of gunicorn. The following example launches 100 handler threads on the same port, with each handler started through `BaseHTTPServer`. It streams fine, supports multiple connections on 1 port, and generally runs 2X faster than gunicorn too. And you can wrap your socket in SSL if you want that too.

```
import time, threading, socket, SocketServer, BaseHTTPServer

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path != '/':
            self.send_error(404, "Object not found")
            return
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.end_headers()

        # serve up an infinite stream
        i = 0
        while True:
            self.wfile.write("%i " % i)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            i += 1

# Create ONE socket.
addr = ('', 8000)
sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(addr)
sock.listen(5)

# Launch 100 listener threads.
class Thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, i):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.i = i
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()
    def run(self):
        httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(addr, Handler, False)

        # Prevent the HTTP server from re-binding every handler.
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210672/
        httpd.socket = sock
        httpd.server_bind = self.server_close = lambda self: None

        httpd.serve_forever()
[Thread(i) for i in range(100)]
time.sleep(9e9)
```

If you insist on using gunicorn anyway, remember to put it (and all its related packages: wsgi, gevent, flask) in a virtualenv to avoid conflicts with other software.

Comment: @Hejazzmann. BaseHTTPServer starts *and* runs faster, and is more secure due to it being a better implementation with fewer bugs. gunicorn corrupts [paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574849/gunicorn-is-corrupting-sys-path), [headers](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-1000164/), and has multiple package dependencies that will cause bugs in larger projects when people just `pip` things because they think that "virtualenv is irrelevant". Take your pick, but cut the FUD please.

Comment: You don't know what you're talking about. BaseHTTPServer is a base class for a webserver construction. Not meant for production as it lacks security/perf features. Even the higher level SimpleHTTPServer is not recommended:

 "This module defines two classes for implementing HTTP servers (Web servers). Usually, this module isn’t used directly, but is used as a basis for building functioning Web servers. See the SimpleHTTPServer and CGIHTTPServer modules." (...)  "Warning SimpleHTTPServer is not recommended for production. It only implements basic security checks." (python doc)

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn processes are sending "messages" to master process to let it know they are still alive (see https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/workertmp.py#L40). However this is not done during response serving (for example see https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/sync.py#L160) so if it takes longer then timeout the master process kills the worker.

Comment: To keep your answer *alive* you should not only provide links but put some content in your answer so it will be here if the link dies.