# gunicorn is corrupting sys.path

Tags: python, gunicorn

I wrote a simple python program:

```
# /tmp/src/Code.py
import sys
print sys.path

# /tmp/src/Main.py
import Code
```

When I run it with `python src/Main.py`, it works as expected:

```
max% cd /tmp
max% setenv PYTHONPATH src
max% python src/Main.py
['/tmp/src',
 '/tmp/src',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

And just to make sure sys.path is working right, I create a file in the working directory:

```
# /tmp/Code.py
print "I never said to search CWD!!! Your Python is broken."
import sys
print sys.path
```

And the result is the same as above, as expected.

However, when I run in gunicorn I get:

```
max% gunicorn Main:app
2017-08-08 10:30:53 [26913] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 17.5
2017-08-08 10:30:53 [26913] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (26913)
2017-08-08 10:30:53 [26913] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-08-08 10:30:53 [26918] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26918
I never said to search CWD!!! Your Python is broken.
['/tmp',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/tmp/src',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

It appears that gunicorn randomly decided to add PWD to the sys.path. There is nothing in the gunicorn manpage about this.

python configuration:

```
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7.2
MarkupSafe==0.18
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==2.3.0
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
Werkzeug==0.9.4
adium-theme-ubuntu==0.3.4
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
blinker==1.3
chardet==2.0.1
colorama==0.2.5
command-not-found==0.3
debtagshw==0.1
defer==1.0.6
dirspec==13.10
duplicity==0.6.23
gevent==1.0
greenlet==0.4.2
gunicorn==17.5
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.8
itsdangerous==0.22
lockfile==0.8
lxml==3.3.3
oauthlib==0.6.1
oneconf==0.3.7.14.04.1
pexpect==3.1
piston-mini-client==0.7.5
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycups==1.9.66
pygobject==3.12.0
pyinotify==0.9.4
pyserial==2.6
pysmbc==1.0.14.1
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
pyxdg==0.25
reportlab==3.0
requests==2.2.1
sessioninstaller==0.0.0
simplejson==3.3.1
six==1.5.2
software-center-aptd-plugins==0.0.0
ssh-import-id==3.21
system-service==0.1.6
unity-lens-photos==1.0
urllib3==1.7.1
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xdiagnose==3.6.3build2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

I know I could remove PWD from the sys.path by searching `realpath(p) == realpath('.')` but sometimes we want PWD in the PYTHONPATH. So a more careful solution is needed. Ideally we would try to figure out which piece of software is introducing the bug. It might simply be that the gunicorn manpage is incomplete?

Comment: I found `gunicorn --pythonpath src` works better than `setenv PYTHONPATH src`. I wish gunicorn had actual documentation.

Comment: It appears that gunicorn is prepending `--pythonpath` in front of PWD and then `PYTHONPATH`. So always running gunicorn with `--pythonpath $PYTHONPATH` should be a general solution. This really should be added to the manpage.

Comment: describe how you solved your problem as an answer to the question, then approve it.

Comment: No, no. It turns out the `--pythonpath` is not reliable. On gunicorn 19.6.0, the PWD still gets inserted in front of the path.

Comment: It appears that if you hack `wsgiapp.py` as shown in my answer below, then `--pythonpath` works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py` and change  the following line:

```
sys.path.insert(0, cwd)
```

to:

```
sys.path.append(cwd)
```

Then `--pythonpath` works as expected.

Comment: How do we make a standard python package that executes the edit shown above? Let's call our package `gunicorn_pythonpath_enabler` or somesuch.

Comment: Making a pull-request to Gunicorn would be more efficient than packaging a patch in some lib.

Answer (score -1):

I switched to `BaseHTTPServer` because it's 2X faster (my application has to scale *efficiently*).

And it's pre-installed in Python 2.7.

And it can stream:
[Python 2.7: streaming HTTP server supporting multiple connections on one port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210672/python-2-7-streaming-http-server-supporting-multiple-connections-on-one-port/46228009)

And doesn't mess with standard logging settings:
[time.time() stops the server process silently when using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45555038/time-time-stops-the-server-process-silently/45576766#45576766)

And doesn't require me to hack WSGI.

And doesn't require 4 packages (gunicorn, gevent, flask, wsgi, werkzeug).

And the code base is much more stable.

And it's easier to understand what it's doing.

And users can just run `./app -arg` instead of `/usr/bin/gunicorn 'app:build_app("-arg")'`

How many reasons do I need???

Comment: Sure, `BaseHTTPServer` is small, but it has practically no features. What are you doing? If you just want to statically serve files, a server like Nginx may be better.

Comment: @Nick I am Implementing a multithreaded service with a RESTful API and a database embedded in the server that various types of clients connect to, for submitting tasks, retrieving work handles, performing administration, etc. With scaling efficiency requirements. Note: SQL was way too slow for this application.

Comment: @Nick please be more specific on which gunicorn features are actually useful to have in a package. When I got rid of it, I saved 30 lines of workaround code, which was greater than the 15 lines I had to add to get back Flask-like URL decorators and response code sugar.

Comment: Whichever application server one prefers, this *doesn't actually answer the question about GUnicorn*.

Comment: @Charles Um, yes it does. The question was what to do about this problem with gunicorn. This was the best answer for me. Besides, my other answer got 0 votes.

Comment: Not any more than "use C instead" is an answer to a problem with Python. It might be something a person could do, but it isn't a topical answer to the question *about Python* (or, in this case, about GUnicorn).

Comment: @Charles I gave a "topical answer" already. See above. Go hack your WSGI. That might be the best answer for you. But it wasn't the best answer for *me*. StackOverflow allows multiple answers; many will work for some people but not others. It is not reasonable to expect one answer to work for *all* people.

Comment: Hey somebody just voted for my other answer! Cool! 20% more reputation!! Ooooohh yeah.

Comment: That was me. It's topical, after all. :)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. <long pause> Now this is an interesting situation... If I accepted one answer but the other answer gets infinitely more votes, what does StackOverflow do?

Comment: IIRC there's a point when a sufficiently-upvoted answer is ordered above the selected one, but I don't remember where that is.

Comment: @Nick Also keep in mind that many of the "features" provided in complex packages are there only to work around basic things (like streaming) that said complex package has obfuscated. In other words, you wouldn't need so many features if you just started with a simpler framework.